# report folder does not exist error with htmlpublisher

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write a jenkins pipeline script for one of my playwright test. Below is one simple code which i have done so far.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    
    stage('Run Playwright Test') {
      steps {
        runTest()
      }
     
    }
    stage('Publish Report'){
       steps {
                script {
                   
                    sh 'ls -lrta'
                    //print REPORT_FILES
                }
                publishHTML([
                            allowMissing: false,
                            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                            keepAll: true,
                            //reportDir: '.',
                            reportDir  : "./TestReport2",
                            reportFiles: 'index.html',
                            reportName: "Html Reports",
                            reportTitles: 'Report title'
                        ])
                         
            }
  }
}
}

def runTest() {
            node('MYNODE') {
                    docker.image('image details').inside('--user root'){
                        git branch: 'mybranchName',credentialsId: 'ID, url: 'url'
                        catchError() {
                            sh """
                            
                            cd WebTests
                            npm install
                            npx playwright test --project=CHROME_TEST --grep @hello
                            """
                        }
                        
                        sh "cp -R WebTests/TestReport TestReport2"
                        sh 'cd TestReport2; ls -lrta'
                        
                        
                       
}
```

When I use the above code, the test executed successfully however i am seeing an error while trying to publish the report.

Below is the error :

Specified HTML directory '/bld/workspace//TestReport2' does not exist.

observation: when i put a ls -ltr after the runTest code i could not see the TestReport2 folder even if it was copied successfully.

Another thing i tried is when i put the code to publish the HTML as part of the runTest() it worked fine and i am able to see the reports generated. Something is going on with the TestReport2 folder when the block of code for runTest() is completed.

Does anyone have an eye on what is the root cause. Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: `WebTests` is your jenkins job name or a folder in your source code repo?  From the error `Specified HTML directory '/bld/workspace//TestReport2' does not exist.` the `'/bld/workspace//TestReport2'` missed the folder for jenkins job workspace,  the expect value should be `'/bld/workspace/{jenkins job name}/TestReport2'`, it's wired the jenkins job workspace part missed.    The reason why publish HTML code block work inside runTest(), it's he run inside the container where the report folder also exists, so he can find report folder.

Comment: When you put publish HTML in another stage, he work outside container, and the container had stopped when he work in another stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stash unstash to save report
like this:

stash includes: "TestReport2/index.html", name: "htmlreport" in runTest()
ustash "htmlreport" in Publish Report stage